# OSX 10.10.2 - cmd start undefined showing

Tags: macos, google-chrome, go

How to fix it? (OSX 10.10.2, go version go1.4.2 darwin/amd64)

#### Error:

> cmd.Start undefined (type string has no field or method Start)

#### Code:

```
  myos := runtime.GOOS;
  myarch := runtime.GOARCH;
  const url = "http://localhsot:9090"
  if myarch == "386" {
      cmd := exec.Command("open", "-b" , "com.google.Chrome", "--args", "--chrome-frame", "--kiosk", url);
    } else {
      cmd := exec.Command("open", "-b" , "com.google.Chrome", "--args", "--chrome-frame", "--kiosk", url);
    }
    err := cmd.Start();
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("failed");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `cmd` variable is shadowing a `cmd` parameter in an enclosing function (not visible in the OP's question), then the `cmd := exec.Command` would declare a new `cmd` ([short variable declaration form](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)) which wouldn't be visible outside of the `if/else` scope.

The [OP YumYumYum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285594/yumyumyum) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122372/osx-10-10-2-cmd-start-undefined-showing/29122461?noredirect=1#comment46471229_29122461):

> I had this: `func main() { cmd := "";`

This is a short variable declaration associating the type string to `cmd`.
That wouldn't work well with [`exec.Command() *exec.Cmd`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command), which returns a `*exec.Cmd`.

If would be better to declare a `var cmdopen *exec.Cmd` (different name, just to be on the safe side) and instantiates it, in order to be sure that the `cmdopen` is from the expected type `*exec.Cmd`.

```
var cmdopen *exec.Cmd
if myarch == "386" {
    cmdopen = exec.Command("open", "-b", "com.google.Chrome", "--args", "--chrome-frame", "--kiosk", url)
} else {
    cmdopen = exec.Command("open", "-b", "com.google.Chrome", "--args", "--chrome-frame", "--kiosk", url)
}
err := cmdopen.Start()
```

(note the use of '`=`' instead of '`:=`' in `cmdopen = exec.Command`)

Comment: @YumYumYum ok, same kind of issue then. The second part of my answer describe a way to avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: @YumYumYum I stand by my answer: declare a *separate* variable of the right type, then use it.

Comment: I applied like you said in OSX 10.10.2 i have now new error: "undefined: Cmd " when i said `var cmd *Cmd;`

Comment: @YumYumYum yes, the actual type is `*exec.Cmd` (http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd). I have edited the answer.